# How can I write multiple conditions in CASE statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, case

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycol = mycol +
           (CASE id
              WHEN ? THEN 5
              WHEN ? THEN 10
              WHEN ? THEN 15
              WHEN ? THEN 20
           END)
WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Well I need to investigate one more condition for all of those conditions. So I write my query like this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycol = mycol +
           (CASE
              WHEN id = ? AND $bool THEN 5
              WHEN id = ? AND $bool THEN 10
              WHEN id = ? AND $bool THEN 15
              WHEN id = ? AND $bool THEN 20
           END)
WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

This ^ query works. But as you see I've wrote a constant condition *(`$bool` - this is a PHP variable which is containing `1` or `0`)* several times. Now I'm looking for a MySQL syntax to lets me I write `$bool` once for all cases. Is that possible?

Comment: What if `$bool` is false? Which value do you want the `CASE` expression to return?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos If `$bool` is *false*, then `CASE` expression should return nothing (`0`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IF`:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET mycol = mycol + IF($bool, (CASE
                                  WHEN id = ? THEN 5
                                  WHEN id = ? THEN 10
                                  WHEN id = ? THEN 15
                                  WHEN id = ? THEN 20
                               END), 0)
WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

If `$bool` is `true` then the value returned by the `CASE` expression will be added to `mycol`, otherwise `0` is added.

Comment: Just may you please tell me how this works? `SET rep = rep + (CASE WHEN id = 1234 THEN 2 WHEN id = 5678 AND FALSE THEN 15 END)`. I mean what happens for that `id = 5678` ?

Comment: How did you understand this? :S +1

Comment: `id =5678 AND FALSE` will always be false, so it will never get the value `15`

Comment: @sagi Yes I know that, I mean what happens for this? `rep = rep + {when condition is connected with FALSE by AND}` ? In other word that `CASE` expression what returns?

Comment: @stack When `id = 1234` it returns `2`, otherwise it returns `NULL`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I see, So `rep = rep + NULL` is still `rep`? I mean the value of `rep` doesn't change, am I right?

Comment: @stack No,  `rep + NULL` evaluates to `NULL` not `rep`.

Comment: Oh .. Do you mean everything plus with `NULL` will be `NULL` ?

Comment: @stack Yes, its like saying: add something to something else that is *not known*. The result will be *not known*.

Comment: If you have some free time please take a look at [this pretty similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859978/how-to-replace-null-with-0-in-the-query)

Comment: In your query, I think you can write `id` once after `CASE` and remove it for each case.