# How to replace NULL with 0 in the query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
$db->prepare("UPDATE users 
               SET reputation = reputation +
                               (CASE WHEN id = ? THEN 2
                                     WHEN id = ? AND NOT ? THEN 15 END)
              WHERE id IN (?, ?); ")
->execute(array($author_ques_id, $author_ans_id, $isOwnAnswer,
                $author_ans_id, $author_ques_id));
```

Please focus on this line:

```
WHEN id = ? AND NOT ? THEN 15 END)
```

When `NOT ?` is *false* *(in other word `$isOwnAnswer = true`)*, the value of `reputatuin` for such a user will be `NULL`. Because `reputation = reputation + NULL` evaluates `reputation = NULL`.

Well how can I prevent of that? I want when that condition is *false*, then `reputation` doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to wrap it with another `CASE/COALESCE/IFNULL` or anything, just use the `CASE EXPRESSION` `ELSE` , in case all the conditions are not met, the `ELSE` will be used.

```
UPDATE users 
           SET reputation = reputation +
                            CASE WHEN id = ? THEN 2
                                 WHEN id = ? AND NOT ? THEN 15
                                 ELSE 0
                            END
          WHERE id IN (?, ?);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
UPDATE users 
SET reputation = reputation +
                 COALESCE((CASE 
                             WHEN id = ? THEN 2
                             WHEN id = ? AND NOT ? THEN 15 
                           END), 0)
```

Comment: @stack Its the same thing, I don't think it makes any difference performance-wise.

Comment: `COALESCE` returns the first non-null argument, or null if all of them are null. `COALESCE` is more cross-platform. `IFNULL` is not available in other vendors' products, while `COALESCE` is part of the SQL standard and implemented by most of the DBMSes